# Is bad code on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Obvously, 'bad code' is on-topic for many definitions of 'bad code'.  The particular class of badness I'm asking about is code that:

- is unclear without an in-depth knowledge of code standards or
  requires lookup of such standards.
- could be easily rewritten to make the functionality obvious
- could be easily rewritten to avoid mental breakdowns to
  debugging/maintenance/enhancement engineers
- would cause the originating programmer to get fired if in an industry setting
- is an extremely bad contribution to a 'repository of knowledge' and a
  poor example for the more inexperienced developers who use this 
  site

This question was prompted by this exchange:

[++*p++ does'nt work on second element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467848/p-doesnt-work-on-second-element-in-array)

Such practices are rarely seen outside homework questions because industry developers who wrote such code are now slinging burgers.  I do a lot of maintenance/enhancement work and so have an intense dislike of such questions/code.  I suspect most of them are assignment dumps and would like to see such code gone from SO.

I searched for 'Is bad code on-topic' here first:)

Comment: *"because industry developers who wrote such code are now slinging burgers"* ... I think you maybe somewhat too optimistic there.

Comment: But no, bad code isn't by definition off topic. Your "easily" seems to imply "someone who knows what he's doing". In which case there was no need for the specific question to begin with. If the problem here isn't a duplicate to begin with or should be closed for other standard reasons, I'm sure you can come up with a great answer that informs the OP of what the problem is, as well as why what he has written is bad/poor/not up to standards. And if you do so in a polite, easy to understand and informative manner, then there is your lasting value.

Comment: @Bart, you mistakenly typed your answer in the comment box...

Comment: @Bart OK, but that requires considerable effort for little gain, and I would have to repeat it tomorrow, and the day after..., as students realize that they can get their own bad-code assignments done too:(   Also, I would probably answer incorrectly anyway because I don't write such code..  If I did, I would have a lot of trouble debugging/maintaining it or, I guess, I could just post it on SO...

Comment: ... so ... don't answer?

Comment: ... and downvote, don't forget to downvote. That's usually the expected thing to do when you really dislike something with this kind of passion.

Comment: Just because you *can* answer a question doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: I think you've latched on to the wrong comment. I don't think anyone was implying that what was being asked was off-topic except for one.  That one comment you are probably referring to made it seem that way.  If anything, the comments are questioning the practicality of the question which is (I think we all can agree on) pointless.

Comment: I'm amazed anyone would assume this is bad student code.  I used to grade c++ student code and have seen it's horrors first hand.  This code shows effort has been made to make it bad.  It is far more typical to find such code in certification questions.

Comment: Is there a reason to assume the 'bad code' is production code and judge it accordingly? The question you linked in particular struck me as "here's a thing I noticed... why does it happen?" rather than "please help me fix my [terrible] code."

Comment: Exactly, so pointing out that the code is done in a terrible style that should be refactored is appropriate.  But the question still deserves an answer.  Not down and close votes.

Comment: @MartinJames I think your question is bad, we are here to help and help we shall, stop being so negative dude if you dont like the question move on to another question

Answer (score 42):

Yes, bad code *is* on topic. We're here to help people, including those that are bad at their job. Hopefully we can give advice so they suck less in the future. Or sometimes the bad code they're asking about is someone else's horrible code they have to maintain.

And don't downvote questions *containing bad code*, downvote them for writing bad *questions*.

Comment: Well I would already be happy if the askers just show some minimal effort/code. But most of the time you don't even see code.

Comment: There is sometimes a climate of negativity on SO. It's nice to hear people expressing the "we're here to help" attitude. To me the only bad questions are ones that are trying to elicit a complete solution, with no effort made by the questioner.

Comment: @jsj this. The only [negatively voted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19055847/1082449) I've ever posted really frustrated me because it's a perfectly well formulated question, but people downvoted it simply because they considered what I was attempting a bad practice, and the only answer (which IIRC received several upvotes originally) ignored the question completely and simply stated this opinion. There was some vote correction eventually, to round everything pretty much to zero, but sometimes SO is not so much a Q&A site as an opinion popularity contest forum </rant>

Comment: @davnicwil: 2 downvotes, one upvote. Big deal, you still came out ahead. (And now you've got a second upvote...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe , bad code is perfectly on topic , unless the question doesn't make sense.
I am the OP of the question posted there , and I believe that people here are to help each other. And as far as the style matters(as most people on the thread complaining about me unnecessarily obfuscate code) , I believe knowledge is more important than showing off style (and it's a perfectly valid C code!). And the only one reason for anyone not having the solution to that problem (and who're bolstering it to be overly obfuscated) is one's inability to solve it. And just because you have some specific profession (or have your personal preferences) doesn't mean you criticize people having genuine doubts.

P.S: This question was asked to me at my interview for Google